# How to prove martingality of forward rate under T-forward measure

Tags: interest-rates, martingale, forward-rate, numerairechange

Let $P(t,T)=\mathbb{E}_{Q_{R}}[e^{\int^{T}_{t}r(u)du}|\mathcal{F}_{t}]$ be the price of a 1-euro zero-coupon bond with maturity $T$ and $r(u)$ the interest rate process. Consider the the forward rate $\frac{-\partial \log P(t,T)}{\partial T}$. How to prove that the forward is a martingale under $Q_{T}$? $Q_{T}$ is the T-forward measure with $P(t,T)$ as the numeraire.

It feels like a very basic question, however I truly cannot find any proofs on the internet.

Comment: Heuristically $d(logP) = dP/P$ so the forward is the limit of $(P(t,T)-P(t,T+dT))/P(t,T)$.   This latter is the ratio of asset prices with P(t,T) in the denominator so is a martingale under the Q measure.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are interested in a) the forward, b) the forward rate, or c) the instantaneous forward rate? The rate you have defined is the _instantaneous_ forward rate, whereas in the answer below the forward rate is used.

Comment: My lecture notes tated forward rate, but I guess it is about the instantaneous forward rate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the instantaneous forward, please see the last page of this note: T-Forward Measure by Fabrice Douglas Rouah (http://www.frouah.com/finance%20notes/The%20T-Forward%20Measure.pdf).

For the simple forward, you know the relationship between the price of the zero coupon and the simple forward:

$ \frac{P \left(t,T_{n}\right)}{P \left(t,T_{n+1}\right)  }=1+\tau F \left(t,T_n \right)$

Which you can rearrange to get:

$F \left(t,T_n \right)P \left(t,T_{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{\tau} \left(P \left(t,T_{n}\right)-P \left(t,T_{n+1}\right)\right)$

So the left hand side is the price of an asset as it is a difference of the price of two bonds divided by the time fraction (accrual factor). And if you use $P \left(t,T_{n+1} \right)$ as a numeraire, then you get from the general valuation formula:

$ \frac{F \left(t,T_n \right)P \left(t,T_{n+1}\right)}{P \left(t,T_{n+1}\right)}=E^{T} \left[ \left. \frac{F \left(S,T_n \right)P \left(S,T_{n+1}\right)}{P \left(S,T_{n+1}\right)} \right| \mathcal{F}_t\right] $

And simple algebra gives:

$F \left(t,T_n \right)=E^{T} \left[ \left. F \left(S,T_n \right)\right| \mathcal{F}_t\right] $

Answer (score 5):

By definition,
$$Fo(t,T)=E^T[S_T|F_t]$$
Note that expectation is taken under $T$-forward measure. Now, evaluating at $s<T$:
$$E^T[Fo(t,T)|F_s] = E^T[E^T[S_T|F_t]|F_s] = E^T[S_T|F_s] = Fo(s,T)$$
(using the tower property of expectations). Hence Forwards rate is a martingale under the T-forward measure.

Comment: What is $S_T$ here?

Comment: @ReneRecktenwald it refers to the Equity price at time 'T'

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @Prabhnoor Duggal is correct. Here, I would like to further expand to make it more streamlined (see also Section 2.5 of the book [Interest Rate Models - Theory and Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540221492)). Let $Q$ and $Q^T$ be the risk-neutral and the $T$-forward respective probability measures. Then, for $0\le t \le T$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dQ}{dQ^T}\big|_{[t, T]} = \frac{B_TP(t, T)}{B_t}.
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
f(t, T) &= \frac{-\frac{\partial }{\partial T}P(t, T)}{P(t, T)}\\
&=\frac{E_Q\left(e^{-\int_t^Tr_s ds}\, r_T\,|\, \mathscr{F}_t \right)}{P(t, T)}\\
&=\frac{E_{Q^T}\left(\frac{dQ}{dQ^T}\big|_{[t, T]}\,e^{-\int_t^Tr_s ds}\, r_T\,|\, \mathscr{F}_t \right)}{P(t, T)}\\
&=E_{Q^T}(r_T \,|\,\mathscr{F}_t).
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\{f(t, T), \, 0\le t \le T\}$ is a martingale under the $T$-forward probability measure.